# Си. Прерывание записи строки неизвестного размера в динамический массив

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы, malloc, realloc

**на вход будет даваться две строки, размеры строк заранее неизвестны, каждая строка будет кончаться нажатием Enter.** Я написал функцию, которая получает параметром & на заранее объявленный массив.

**Проблема: не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия Enter цикл заканчивался и программа шла дальше.** Предполагаемый символ Enter должен быть на месте **EOF**, пробовал написать туда "\0" - не работает!

Пожалуйста, не предлагайте другие варианты реализации кроме как malloc, realloc, ибо **для задачи нужны именно динамические массивы**. Заранее спасибо!

```
void create_array(char** arr){
     char capacity = 8;
     int i = 0;
     (*arr) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * capacity);
     while (scanf("%c", (*arr + i)) != EOF){
         i++;
         if (i == capacity){
             capacity *= 2;
             (*arr) = (char*)realloc((*arr), sizeof(char) * capacity);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `int tmp; while ( (tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF ) {*(*arr + i) = tmp; ...}` + не забудьте добавить нулевой символ в конце строки.

Comment: решение рабочее, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int tmp; while ( (tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF ) {*(*arr + i) = tmp; ...} 

// + не забудьте добавить нулевой символ в конце строки.
```

верное решение от wololo в комментарии.